# sudo dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-*.deb giving "not a debian format archive" error

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu-14.04, mod-pagespeed

The following apparently trivial two initial steps to install mod-pagespeed resulted in the error,

```
'mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
```

even though the first (wget) step appeared to work properly.

```
wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-*.deb
```

What might be going wrong and how to fix that?

Comment: Why the down vote, and without comment? Is it badly worded? I realise it isn't a new issue (as I drew attention to in the answer) but it took several hours of a sys admin's time and mine to get to the bottom of and fix this. It might save someone else those same hours.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the .deb file was much smaller than expected and its content indicated that "this product is not available in your country," even though the server was meant to be in the UK, and https://www.countryipblocks.net/ agreed that it was in the UK. (http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup said it was in the US.)

The solution was simply to go to the Google download page for the module, https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download, do a local download (eg right click the appropriate link and do "Save link as ..." in Firefox), and then upload that to the server.

It then built fine.

(I found this solution in a comment about a different problem at http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20120514/how-do-i-install-modpagespeed, which speculated that "server's IP was somehow mistraced by Google to some weird country or something" - could this be the underlying cause?)

Edit: Possible gotcha: Later problems with apt-get update with a GPG error (fatal) with the mod-pagespeed installation being the very smoky gun. It was a mess to sort out.